# ABBYY FlexiCapture 12 api - Problem with upload project to server

Tags: abbyy

When I try upload the project to server I receive the error: "this user is not on this server". Although I created tenant.

[ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MumGc.png)

[ss2(error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGtTb.png)

[ss3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oUTH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tenants have different users.
Check that user exists on tenant.
And check that user has Project Administrator rights on tenant to be able to upload the project.